# How do you use javascript to handle appended HTML ID's?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wysiwyg, nicedit

This line of javascript assigns a WYSIWYG editor to an element with the HTML ID 'description'.

```
 new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('description')
```

The WYSIWYG editor then overrides the textarea.

```
 <textarea 

   id="description[<?php echo $pid ?>]" 
   name="description[<?php echo $pid?>]" 

 </textarea>
```

But the ID tag changes as it iterates through all of the descriptions. The current $pid of the description is appended to the ID tag. (description1, description2 etc.)

How do you modify the javascript to handle each appended ID name?

```
new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance('description.???')
```

Comment: Sounds like it has already handled that for you, by giving them desc1, desc2, desc3 etc. Are you trying to get a handle on the elements after they are appened?

Comment: Why would you need more than one wysiwyg editor on the page at any given time?

Comment: There needs to be an 12 editors per page, all of which will have different IDs, description56, description4, description78. How do I tell javascript that it applies to every element that starts with 'description'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like niEditor supports assigning to classes, you might be better off using [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) with the [selector](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aselector) option and assigning the same class to each textarea.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is not that complicated. I simply want to apply the script to every ID which starts with 'description'??